# How to detemine if the default value was supplied to stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

There's a stored procedure with the parameter that may take default value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FooSP] 
    @FooParam INT = 15
AS
```

So is there a way to determine whether that SP was called with or without setting the @FooParam value.

IOW, is there a way to determine if the user called

```
exec dbo.FooSP(15)
```

or

```
exec dbo.FooSP()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would there be any difference between the two?

Comment: "Why would there be any difference between the two?"

That's why i'm asking.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do that, you are usually better off changing the default value to some kind of sentinal value (NULL often works well in db stored procedures,) and putting some logic in the procedure to set the value to you old default (15 in this case) if NULL is received.

That way, you get the benefit of a default value, and the ability to know what was passed in.

**UPDATE**

If there is no possible sentinal value -- say, because the parameter is very constrained, where all possible inputs are legitimate, then you will have to either do some stack introspection, or change the function signature.

If you can change the calling code, then make the procedure with the default parameter *actually a different procedure*, which then calls your original procedure with the default set explicitly.

Comment: Ian, thanks for the answer.
I thought about that, but in my original example there's a BIT datatype, so basically, just 3 values: True, False and NULL.
So I'm trying to figure out if I can distinct default NULL value from the one that came from the user.

Comment: Yes, I had to change procedure signature, that was the most suitable way to solve that.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to vote for [this related Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124537&wa=wsignin1.0) - getting call stack information can be really useful to be able to instrument code, and debug situations.